# Running Netlogo using 64-bit java

Tags: java, netlogo

How can I run NetLogo using 64-bit java version without using cmd as below.[image]

I doing because I wish to R-extension in Netlogo using 64 bit java. On loading it in 32 bit it closes immediately.

Again, I don't wish to use cmd every time to start NetLogo. Moreover, starting an NetLogo instance from R also adds to it.

Comment: Please explain if anything is wrong with the question, I find it unanswered elsewhere, no 64-bit launcher is available to address the issue.

Comment: see also https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/423

Comment: Can you expand on why you want this?  If it's just so it's clickable why don't you just put the above two commands in a batch script and then you have your launcher.  e.g. saving this as `64-bit-launch.bat` in the Netlogo directory works for me: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Netlogo 5.1.0"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\Java.exe" -jar NetLogo.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but didn't initially realise it was due to java incompatibility. See this [Cannot make R-extension work in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345640/cannot-make-r-extension-work-in-netlogo/33393983#33393983) for solution. Briefly, change the R installation rather than try and adjust NetLogo and have the 32bit R in the path.